# creating agents on specific patches

Tags: netlogo

I'm a beginner  with netlogo and I'm having trouble creating agents in a specific setting. I have a world with urban spaces with different colors and green spaces defined as `[pcolor = green]` and I'm trying to make agents appear everywhere but with a higher concentration the closest you get to the green spaces. So far I have only been able to make them appear in green spaces with this :

```
ask n-of 1000 patches with [pcolor = green]    
[sprout-Proies 1 ]
```

could anyone help me with this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: Okay, so you've got a rough idea of what you want to do. In order to turn it into code, first you'll need to decide precisely what rule you are trying to implement. If you can restate "with a higher concentration the closer you get" in precise, mathematical language, you'll be halfway to a solution.

Comment: thank you for your help, 
what comes to mind is something that would ressemble this :
ask n-of patches that are 50 to 0 patches away from a green patch to sprout "proies" 
then ask n-of partches that are 100 to 50 patches away from a green to sprout "proies" 

and so on but I'm not sure it's the most efficient way

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not an exact solution, you can try writing:

```
ask n-of 1000 patches with [pcolor = green]    
[sprout-Proies 1 [fd random 10]]
```

Basically, just sprout the turtles on the patches and then spread them from there.